# Nature of a stochastic process

Tags: arima, econometrics, stochastic-processes, garch

I am a econometrics student, and I've to understand what type of process the one in the image below is. I am not able to go back to the main classic stochastic processes (AR, MA, ARMA, ARCH/GARCH). In particular, the fact that epsilon is multiplied and not added generated confusion in me. Epsilon is a Gaussian white noise Thanks!

[image]

Comment: So $\{X_t\}$ is a complex valued? Are you sure $\epsilon_t$ is Gaussian (rather than something else like lognormal)?

Comment: Yes, epsilon is the disturbance distribuited as a Normal. {Xt} is simply the value of the process at time t. But for example in an Autoregressive process I expect that the disturbance is added not multiplied.

Comment: For $X_t$ to be well-defined, you need to specify *which* square root you are taking, especially (but not only) for negative or complex values. If this isn't perfectly clear, write a (simple) program to simulate a realization of this process: it will run into trouble the first time $X_{t-1}$ is negative, which will happen quickly.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the answer. The exercise must be done without any simulation, it's a written test. I have to tell which type of process is it among the ones studied during the course, and then obtain the autocorrelation function. I think we'are dealing only with real numbers.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest you solve it with simulation.  I'm trying to impress upon you that your question is unanswerable as stated.  I suspect a typographical error and/or lack of appropriate assumptions, as hinted at by @MatthewGunn. A couple minutes spent with a simulation will help you understand these points.

Comment: @whuber  another assumption made is that Xt is a stationary process

Comment: Here's an `R` simulation for you to play with.  "8" is the length of the sequence.  `Reduce(function(x,e) sqrt(0.5*x)*e, rnorm(8), accumulate=TRUE)`.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, there is a typo inside the square root, the correct exercise is : sqrt(4+0.5*x)*e'. I forgot the costant. Thanks for the simulation

Comment: That still won't work.  The basic problem is that eventually you are certain to obtain a negative value inside the square root.  For instance, I modified the simulation according to your edit, set the random number seed to 17, and ran it for a length of 800; it failed at $t=275.$  Here's the full run: `set.seed(17); x <- Reduce(function(x,e) sqrt(4+0.5*x)*e, rnorm(800), accumulate=TRUE);
plot(x, type="l")` If you change `rnorm(800)` to `exp(rnorm(800))` you will obtain not only an interesting, complete series, but you will have something you can successfully analyze.

Comment: @whuber I've changed numbers putting sqrt(2+0.14*x)*e. Now the code seems to always work, obtaining the process for all t. Can we analyze that?

Comment: Now you're just fishing for an answerable question!  With the change in values the expected time until your simulation demonstrates the model is not well-defined becomes (very) large--but it's still finite. It's time to return to your original source and check it.

Comment: @whuber just a question, in the case of a process of the type: Xt=0.4*Xt-1*e : the fact that the noise is multiplied and not added to the rest makes difference? Or is still an AR1?

Comment: Yes, multiplicative noise makes a difference.  But there is no problem with it because you aren't trying to take square roots of negative numbers.  It's not AR-1, as you can check by consulting the definition.

Comment: @whuber really thanks for all the answers. There was a typo in the original source. Thanks a lot